# Inheritance of static class properties

Tags: javascript

Static class properties are inherited:

```js
const foo = class { static prop = 'this is a static prop' }
const bar = class extends foo {}
console.log(bar.prop) // 'this is a static prop'
```

But I thought static properties were akin to the following, which prints `undefined` as expected:

```js
const foo = function() {}
foo.prop = 'this is a static prop'
const bar = function() {}
bar.prototype = Object.create(foo.prototype)
bar.prototype.constructor = bar
console.log(bar.prop) // undefined
```

So is static class property inheritance magical behavior provided over and above ordinary prototypical inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `extends` does this for you: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). You certainly can do an old-school copy/extends for the same behavior.